# Rspec2 nested resources broken redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, rspec-rails

I'm trying to write a Rspec test for my nested autolinks_controller. However, the redirect after my create action is broken. After successfully creating an autolink I want to be redirected to that autolink within a particular website (hence, website_autolink_path). My controller spec looks like this:

```
describe "POST create when params[:website_id] are present" do
  before(:each) do
    @website = create(:website)
    @autolink = attributes_for(:website_autolink, website_id: @website.id)
  end

  context "with valid attributes and params[:website_id] are present" do
        it "saved the autolink in the database" do
            expect{
                post :create, website_id: @website, autolink: attributes_for(:website_autolink)
            }.to change(Autolink, :count).by(1)
        end

        it "redirects to the 'index' page" do
            post :create, website_autolink: @autolink, website_id: @website
            response.should redirect_to website_autolink_path
        end
    end
end
```

This line is not working:

```
response.should redirect_to website_autolink_path
```

Giving me the error message:

```
ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"autolinks"}
```

My factories look like this:

Autolink:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :website_autolink do
    name "MyName"
    url "http://www.myurl.nl"
    association :website
  end 
end
```

Website:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :website do
    name "Test"
    domain "http://www.test.nl"
  end 
end
```

My AutolinkController:

```
def create
    if params[:website_id].present?
        @website = Website.find(params[:website_id])
        @autolink = @website.autolinks.create(params[:autolink])
    else
        @autolink = Autolink.new(params[:autolink])
    end

    respond_to do |format|
        if @autolink.save
            if params[:website_id].present?
                format.html { redirect_to [@website, @autolink], notice: "Autolink is met succes aangemaakt." }
            else
                format.html { redirect_to autolinks_path, notice: "Autolink is met succes aangemaakt." }
            end
            format.json { head :no_content }
        else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @autolink.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
         end
    end
end
```

Within my controller, the following line is the one I want to simulate using Rspec:

```
format.html { redirect_to [@website, @autolink], notice: "Autolink is met succes aangemaakt." }
```

In my localhost it's all working, but writing the actual test for this nested route troubles me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a solution for my problem. My controller spec for the create action now looks like this:

```
describe "POST create when params[:website_id] are present" do
  context "with valid attributes and params[:website_id] are present" do
    before(:each) do
        @website = create(:website)
        @autolink = attributes_for(:website_autolink, website: @website)
      end

        it "saved the autolink in the database" do
            expect{
                post :create, autolink: @autolink, website_id: @website.id
            }.to change(Autolink, :count).by(1)
        end

        it "redirects to the 'index' page" do
            post :create, autolink: @autolink, website_id: @website.id
            response.should redirect_to website_autolink_path(@website, assigns(:autolink))
        end
    end
end
```

I just had to assign my autolink in order to redirect_to the nested path. Without it, the id of my autolink couldn't be found.